# how do i Disable AJAX error window for constraint?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have an app where an AJAX error window pops up when a constraint for data. I want this AJAX error to not show up. It only does it for one of the fields in the table and not others with similar constraints. Is there a way to get rid of this window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error usually appears when a certain process fails due to your constraint exception.
You can either supply an own error message (this will simply replace the constraint message) or handle the exception yourself, like this:

```
declare
    lExConstraint exception;
    pragma exception_init(lExConstraint, -2290);
begin
    insert into your_table(columnx) values (1);
exception
    when lExConstraint then
        -- do your handling here
        null;
end;
```

In this example, I created an alias for ORA-02290, a check constraint exception - but it could be used in a similar way for all other exceptions. Note that you should not leave the code like this, as it will simply swallow the exception and do nothing.